# Replace character references for invalid XML characters

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am projecting some data as XML from SQL Server using ADO.NET. Some of my data contains characters that are invalid in XML, such as `CHAR(7)` (known as [`BEL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character)).

```
SELECT 'This is BEL: ' + CHAR(7) AS A FOR XML RAW
```

SQL Server [encodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb500235.aspx) such invalid characters as numeric references:

```
<row A="This is BEL: &#x7;" />
```

However, even the encoded form is invalid under XML 1.0, and will give rise to errors in XML parsers:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<row A=\"This is BEL: &#x7;\" />");
// XmlException: ' ', hexadecimal value 0x07, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 25.
```

I would like to replace all these invalid numeric references with the Unicode replacement character, `'�'`. I know how to do this for unencoded XML:

```
string str = "<row A=\"This is BEL: \u0007\" />";
if (str.Any(c => !XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(c)))
    str = new string(str.Select(c => XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(c) ? c : '�').ToArray());
          // <row A="This is BEL: �" />
```

Is there a straightforward way to make it work for encoded XML too? I would prefer to avoid having to [`HtmlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354(v=vs.110).aspx) then [`HtmlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388364(v=vs.110).aspx) the whole string, in order not to risk introducing changes other than invalid character replacement.

**Edit**: The conversion needs to be done in my C# code, not SQL, in order for it to be implemented centrally.

Comment: See following webpage.  XMLTextWriter will automatically replace characters.  You could get the complete list of special character and create a dictionary.  Pretty simple.  The complete list can be found a wiki. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx

Comment: @jdweng: My question is about converting `"&#x7;"` to `"�"`. Your link only discusses how to convert `"\u0007"` to `"&#x7;"`.

Comment: @Douglas What do you want to do with `&#x3C;` . If you convert it to `<` your xml would be invalid. Converting it to `�` will make your text weird.

Comment: A great point... it seems that a library call like `HtmlEncode` and `HtmlDecode` is certainly the way to go here rather than by hand, unless you want to handle a lot of special cases.

Comment: @EZI: I only need to replace invalid character references. `&#x3C;` is valid XML in its encoded form, so it can be left alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made another go at it using regular expressions. This should handle both decimal and hex character codes. Also, this will not affect anything but numerically encoded characters.

```
public string ReplaceXMLEncodedCharacters(string input)
{
    const string pattern = @"&#(x?)([A-Fa-f0-9]+);";
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
    int offset = 0;
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        int charCode = 0;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups[1].Value))
            charCode = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
        else
            charCode = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        char character = (char)charCode;
        input = input.Remove(match.Index - offset, match.Length).Insert(match.Index - offset, character.ToString());
        offset += match.Length - 1;
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again! This is on the lines of what I was going for, throwing in `XmlConvert.IsXmlChar` on the decoded characters. I'll wait a couple of days more in case there's a simpler solution; if not, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the special characters in the [CDATA tag](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp). This informs the parser to ignore text within the tag. To use your example:

```
SELECT 'This is BEL: <![CDATA[' + CHAR(7) + ']]>' AS A FOR XML RAW
```

This will allow the XML to be parsed at the very least, albeit requiring a slight change to the document structure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I can only alter the C# code, not the SQL. (The data is projected from too many places to update them all.)

Comment: No problem! I wasn't sure if changing the structure of the SQL was acceptable, but it's totally understandable that it's not. I hope you find a solution that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is my solution. I've built on [Tonkleton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31616765/1149773), but modified it to match the internal implementation of `HtmlDecode` more closely. The code below ignores surrogate pairs.

```
// numeric character references
static readonly Regex ncrRegex = new Regex("&#x?[A-Fa-f0-9]+;");

static string ReplaceInvalidXmlCharacterReferences(string input)
{
    if (input.IndexOf("&#") == -1)   // optimization
        return input;

    return ncrRegex.Replace(input, match =>
    {
        string ncr = match.Value;            
        uint num;
        var frmt = NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;

        bool isParsed =
            ncr[2] == 'x' ?   // the x must be lowercase in XML documents
            uint.TryParse(ncr.Substring(3, ncr.Length - 4), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, frmt, out num) :
            uint.TryParse(ncr.Substring(2, ncr.Length - 3), NumberStyles.Integer, frmt, out num);

        return isParsed && !XmlConvert.IsXmlChar((char)num) ? "�" : ncr;
    });
}
```

Comment: In modern .NET you may want to replace `match.Value` with `match.ValueSpan` and `ncr.Substring` with `ncr.Slice`.